# Difference between archive.raspbian.org and archive.raspberrypi.org

Tags: raspbian, repository, source.list

I am in the process of setting up a local mirror of the Raspbian repository.
I have successfully mirrored the archive.raspbian.org repo using rsync, however I noticed in the sources.list.d directory there is the following line

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

What packages are stored here? Also what is the idea of splitting between the two sources? I can't seem to find any information describing the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raspbian is the project which recompiles the Debian archive for the Pi architecture. Debian is one of the principal Linux distributions.

raspberrypi.org is the charity and holds packages specifically created for the Pi and which are not part of Raspbian/Debian.