# Why does 'apt install node-body-parser' fail?

Tags: node.js, apt

I have a small Node.js app of my own running on a Raspberry Pi 3 B. A
recent `apt full-upgrade` bumped the nodejs packet from version 4.8.2 to
version 8.11.1, and in the process it removed the package
node-body-parser which I need. Trying to `apt install` it again fails
with a message telling me that either I have requested an impossible
situation or I am using an unstable distribution, and that I have held
broken packages. Here is a transcript with the full message:

```
pi@sionludino:~ $ sudo apt update  
[...]
All packages are up to date.
pi@sionludino:~ $ sudo apt install node-body-parser 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 node-body-parser : Depends: node-raw-body (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: node-iconv (>= 2.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I can't make sense of this error message, which I find quite unhelpful.
Am I requesting “an impossible situation”? Why is it impossible? Is the
distribution I am using (an up to date Raspbian Stretch Lite) considered
“the unstable distribution”? And what does “you have held broken
packages” mean? I have not held anything that I am aware of.

For now, I have worked around this issue by using npm instead apt.
However, since apt is my tool of choice for keeping my computers up to
date, it's quite unsettling for me to see it fail in a way I cannot
understand. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in the Raspbian
(or Debian) packages? If so, should I report it as such? Could I expect
it to be fixed?

**Edit 1**: Following OyaMist Aeroponics’ comment, I googled “apt broken
packages” and followed the advice from the [first
answer](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/):

- The commands `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`,
  `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` ran with no
  errors, but they did not help (`sudo apt install node-body-parser`
  still outputs the same error).
- There is no mention of in node-body-parser in /var/lib/dpkg/status

**Edit 2**: As suggested
[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324151):
`dpkg -l | grep -v '^ii'` does not show any package (only the list
headers), `dpkg --audit` does not dot have any effect.

**Edits 3 & 4**: I don't think I have enabled the backports
repository. Here is my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

The directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d contains a single file named
“raspi.list” with the following content:

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

I tried removing
(`sudo apt purge nodejs; sudo apt autoremove --purge; sudo apt clean`)
and re-installing nodejs. I again got version 8.11.1:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install nodejs 
[...]
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf nodejs armhf 8.11.1~dfsg-2~bpo9+1 [4 126 kB]
[...]
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_8.11.1~dfsg-2~bpo9+1_armhf.deb ...
[...]
```

If I was really installing from backports, shouldn't the string
"backports" appear on the "Get" line over there?

Comment: Have you searched for "apt broken packages"?

Comment: @OyaMistAeroponics: I hadn't, just did, no joy. See edited question. Will go through the other search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I'd recommend using npm for this anyway, *even if you prefer apt*. Generally dependencies for Node.js projects are installed locally per-project rather than system-wide, allowing for multiple, potentially incompatible versions to be used in different projects.

Additionally, Debian's repositories are almost always hopelessly out-of-date with respect to Node packages. That's a consequence of Debian's focus on stability and testing rather than having the cutting edge. However, Node projects often expect you to have the latest packages, and iterate quickly (as opposed to many other tools in the Debian repositories which may only be updated every few years as necessary).

---

> Is the distribution I am using (an up to date Raspbian Stretch Lite) considered “the unstable distribution”?

No. Currently Stretch is 'stable', because it is the latest major release. Packages from the 'sid' repository [are considered unstable](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUnstable).

> And what does “you have held broken packages” mean?

It means that some packages have been marked as [held back](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-mark.8.en.html) and not installed as expected. The 'broken' bit indicates that there is some problem with installing the packages.

> I can't make sense of this error message, which I find quite unhelpful. Am I requesting “an impossible situation”? Why is it impossible?

That's the question which takes a little more than a line to answer!

It appears that `archive.raspberrypi.org` now distribute an updated 8.11.1 version of Node in their repository; the official Debian repostiories distribute [4.8.2](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/nodejs) with Stretch, reserving 8.11.1 for the backports repo.

Anyway, digging to the root of the problem, I think the issue is `node-iconv`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 node-body-parser : Depends: node-raw-body (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: node-iconv (>= 2.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
```

The above tells us that `node-body-parser`  depends on `node-raw-body` and `node-iconv`. What isn't stated there, but makes things more clear, is that [`node-raw-body`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/node-raw-body) also depends on `node-iconv`. So, let's see what [`node-iconv`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/node-iconv) depends on:

> **dep: libc6 (>= 2.17) [arm64, ppc64el]**
> GNU C Library: Shared libraries
> also a virtual package provided by libc6-udeb
>
> **dep: libc6 (>= 2.4) [not arm64, ppc64el]**
>
> **dep: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0)**
> GCC support library
>
> **dep: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1)**
> GNU Standard C++ Library v3
>
> **dep: nodejs**
> evented I/O for V8 javascript
>
> **dep: nodejs-abi-46**
> virtual package provided by nodejs
>
> **dep: nodejs-dev (>= 4.6.0~dfsg-2~)**
> evented I/O for V8 javascript (development files)

The one that looks troubling to me is `nodejs-abi-46`. That looks to be the ABI for Node 4 rather than your Node 8. **That of course leads to an impossible situation**; you have got Node 8 but you are asking to install something which depends on Node 4. So, apt gives up and tells you that it couldn't install `node-iconv`.

Comment: This all makes lots of sense. And indeed, I would expect this kind of incompatibilities... **if** I had installed nodejs from backports. But I don't believe I have. See my edit. BTW, how do you know the latest version for stretch is 4.8.2? The link you provide is for Debian, not for Raspbian.

Comment: @Edgar The package versions for Raspbian are exactly the same as Debian; Raspbian is essentially just Debian with some tweaks and compiled for a slightly different architecture. Raspbian doesn't, however, have such comprehensive web documentation but you can verify it yourself with [`apt-cache`](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-cache.html) if you like. Anyway, I checked the Raspbian Stretch repos, and the package list itself does say `Package: nodejs Version: 4.8.2~dfsg-1`. Could you edit your question to include the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @Edgar, never mind with the sources.list. I've figured out what the discrepancy is. `http://archive.raspberrypi.org` does have the 8.11.1 version, but `http://archive.raspbian.org` has the "correct" version for Stretch (4.8.2). [This question details the differences between the repos](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75834/difference-between-archive-raspbian-org-and-archive-raspberrypi-org/75839)

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly, the bug lies in the raspberrypi.org package archives, which erroneously landed in stretch a package that belongs to stretch-backports. Happy to learn that it was not an error of mine. Do you know where I am supposed to report this kind of “package archive managing” bug?

Answer (score 0):

**Epilogue**

Aurora0001's answer is correct and complete. I am posting this to
summarize my findings, and as an update to tell here how this story
wrapped up.

It appears this issue doesn't affect Raspbian proper. It is specific to
the Raspbian image distributed by the Raspberry Pi foundation, which
enables by default a [repository for foundation-provided
software](http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/).

Whereas the Raspbian repo only distributes nodejs 4.8.2, on July
9th the nodejs 8.11.1 package was uploaded to the foundation repo,
together with nodered, which does require a recent Node.js. Since
nodejs 4.8.2 provides the virtual package `nodejs-abi-46`, and
nodejs 8.11.1 doesn't, this upload made every package depending on
`nodejs-abi-46` uninstallable.

After investigating the issue with the precious help of Aurora0001, I
reported it on the Raspberry Pi forums: [Upgraded nodejs makes some
packages uninstallable](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=219031). User ShiftPlusOne answered saying
that he was the one to do the upload, that he did some testing before
uploading, but did not watch for that particular dependency.

Today (2018-08-01), ShiftPlusOne uploaded updated versions of the
packages that used to depend on `nodejs-abi-46`, and now depend on
`nodejs-abi-57`. My test shows that node-body-parser is installable
again, and it works as expected. I am grateful to ShiftPlusOne for
quickly implementing the fix.